# Publisher oddness & DCP

Tags: tridion

We have a strange issue with DCPs and Publisher (2011 SP1). We've enabled the Publisher log to try and get some clues:

On our DEV env, we have a CT marked as Dynamic & Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly. When we publish the page, the log entry contains:

```
21/05/2012 14:08:41 <8324> Rendering item [tcm:35-8489] 'Brand Master' with template [tcm:35-2001-32] 'Product Detail' in publication target [tcm:0-4-65537] 'IP.Live' 
21/05/2012 14:08:43 <8324> Rendering of item [tcm:35-8489] 'Brand Master' with template [tcm:35-2001-32] 'Product Detail' in publication target [tcm:0-4-65537] 'IP.Live' took: 00:00:01.9611120
```

But on our PROD when we publish the page with the same DCP, the log entry is:

```
21.05.2012 13:37:39 <7416> Resolved item is a Dynamic Component Presentation; only generate a TCDL dynamic link to component [tcm:35-5673] with template [tcm:35-2001-32]
```

Is there some configuration I've missed here that means PROD generates this TCDL link instead of just rendering the template like DEV?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be because the DCP in question was already published before?

The Publisher will do some magic when determining what (not) to render. On my environment I do see this message for DCPS:

```
4/18/2012 4:10:40 PM <7916> Resolved item is a Dynamic Component Presentation; only generate a TCDL dynamic link to component [tcm:28-2711] with template [tcm:28-2751-32]
```

Wonder if anything is different in your DEV? Publication Target language? Template Output Format? (I think Tridion will not publish dynamic stuff if the target or template are not set to a "dynamic" language)

Comment: That was - Target Language. It was set to ASP.NET on PROD and None on DEV! We needed None.